# Slope of a graph

Tags: data-visualization, logarithm

I am plotting some data which should have a positive slope but instead, it has a negative slope (because the values were decreasing with time).
Is there anything to transform the data to have a positive slope?

Comment: Multiplying all y values by $-1$ is a transformation, that comes to my mind and that will make the slope positive. It is a special case of $y' = c_1 - c_2\times y$ transformation with $c_1$ and $c_2$ being constants of your choice. There are lots and lots of alternatives, but you would have to give away a little bit more about **why** a positive slope is of importance in the first place.

Comment: Yes, this is an odd question. Why do you want the slope to be positive? That sounds like a misrepresentation of the data.

Comment: Just reverse time – no one will notice. :-)

Comment: Edit the data by hand to make it say what you want to say. Linus Pauling did it.

Comment: The data don't do what you expect them to; it's important to understand *why* this is so -- there are many things that might cause the direction to be different from expected; however we have no basis on which to offer much advice about it, beyond "don't attempt to change the direction of the relationship".

Answer (score 3):

My favorite professor in grad school (Herman Friedman) used to say:

> If you're not surprised, you haven't learned anything.

You are surprised. That's an opportunity to learn something. Of course, it could be that you just coded things wrong - then all you learn is an aspect of coding. But if you have coded it correctly, then something odd is going on.

Since you haven't told us anything about your data, your variables, your theory or anything else, we can't help you further than that.